# Esri Roads and Highways Extension on Linux ArcGIS Server

Tags: arcgis-server, linux, system-requirements, arcgis-roads-highways, linear-referencing

Is it possible to add Esri Roads and Highways Extension on ArcGIS Server running on Linux?

The products list only includes windows version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Esri, roads and highways is not supported on Linux yet: https://gis.wsu.edu/portal/portalhelp/en/roads-highways/latest/get-started/frequently-asked-questions-about-roads-and-highways-for-server.htm

Answer (score 0):

The [Frequently asked questions about Roads and Highways](https://enterprise.arcgis.com/en/roads-highways/latest/get-started/frequently-asked-questions-about-roads-and-highways-for-server.htm) at a time soon after the release of ArcGIS Enterprise 11.0 (August 2022) say (with my bolding) that:

> The system requirements for Roads and Highways include the system
> requirements for ArcGIS Server; however, Roads and Highways is only
> supported on Windows Server platforms (**not Linux** or UNIX).